# wget using -i with -O

Tags: wget, download, gnu-parallel

I have a db of files to download containing fields for `filename` and `download_url` with the format:

```
"foo-1.23.4.jar", "http://example.com/files/12345678/download"
"bar-5.67.8.jar", "http://example.com/files/9876543/download"
"baz-3.31.jar", "http://example.com/files/42424242/download"
```

Where the urls tend to all be the same except for the number.  I tried exporting the list of URLs and downloading these with `wget -i`, but every file gets named `download`, and I have no way to tell them apart.

Normally I would use the `-O` parameter to specify the correct output file, but I'm not sure how to combine that with `-i`

**How can I format the input file and command line to `wget -i` such that each line can specify both a download url and an output filename?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Concurrently* with GNU **`parallel`**:

```
parallel -a files_list.txt -j0 -C ", *" 'wget -q -O {1} {2}'
```

- `-a input-file` - use `input-file` as input source
- `-j N` - run up to `N` jobs in parallel. `0` means as many as possible
- `-C regex` - column separator. The input will be treated as a table with `regexp` separating the columns. The n'th column can be access using `{n}` or `{n.}`. E.g. `{3}` is the 3rd column

Comment: I like this.  I had not heard of `parallel`.  Does this mean that `wget` does not directly support what I want to do, and the solution is multiple invocations?

Comment: @RyanBemrose, this solution provides you with effective and fast downloading process: you are able to download multiple resources in parallel. Your input file does not fit the wget's `-i` option because it would expect the file to contain only URLs while your file has a more complex structure